# Pop-up modal with UITableView on iPhone (follow)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I've read the post : [Pop-up modal with UITableView on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504478/pop-up-modal-with-uitableview-on-iphone)
and I don't understand the following part of the answer (as I can't comment the original post, I create this new question) :

```
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:optionViewController];
```

Why allocate a new controller as the window from where the new optionController is called may already have one ?

What if I just write :

```
OptionViewController* optionViewController = [[OptionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OptionView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:optionViewController animated:YES];
```

It seems to work...

If I have a list, that goes to a detail View, from where I switch to a modify view, and then from where I call this option window, what would be the code to use to call this optionWindow ? This one ? Any other one ? I really have a problem dealing with UINavigationController between screens... (where should be defined the first one, what should be passed between screens, when may I create a new one, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modal views don't use the `UINavigationController` of their parent. This means that if you need a "stack" of new view controllers in your modal view then you'll need to add your own. On the other hand, if you don't need the functionality of a navigation controller in your modal view then there's no reason to add one.

Here are sone more details of how I did it in two of my apps:

My root view controller has a UINavigationController. I open a modal view using this code:

```
        TwitterPostViewController* vc = [[TwitterPostViewController alloc] init];
        [viewc presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc release];
```

The modal view is then dismissed using this code:

```
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Your code is fine. As I said, there is no need to create a `UINavigationController` unless you actually need one in your modal view.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington : in fact I have continued to code and foudn a possible problem. With my code, I cannont achieve to dismiss the modal view... Any idea about how to do this with this code ? [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES] does not work... of course neither in options view, nor in its parent caller.

Comment: There is no fundamental problem with not using a navigation controller. I do exactly this in one of my apps. `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` is a method of `UIViewController` so just `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]` should do the trick.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington : nope... I thought about it but it just it freezes the app.

Comment: I added a little more detai of how it works. I'm not clear what you mean by "freezes the app." There's nothing in the code you've shown that would do anything that I would classify as a freeze.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington : In fact it does not freeze everytime. I mean by freeze : the list item (I show A UITableView) is shown as selected (blue), and you cannot do anything more. Freeze. It's the [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; called in the first Window that makes all crash (I call the main window from the popup by a delegate method to catch the selection). Another side effect is that I'm not able anymore to dismiss the "popup" window into its own methods.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington : I tried [self dismissModalViewWithAnimation:YES], it does not help.

Comment: I have copy and pasted code from my app (this code has been live in the app store for over a year). It works. If you see different behaviour then you'll need to show more code as these are not the bits that are going wrong.

Comment: @Stephen Darlington : Well... That's a good point for you  :-)  As it works with the navigationController, I'll see this later. But it's strange, really strange...